# Split RDF dataset into two Random datasets

Tags: rdf

I have an RDF dataset with 100M triples from the [watdiv](https://dsg.uwaterloo.ca/watdiv/#installation) RDF benchmark. How can I split this dataset into two smaller randomly-distributed datasets, each with about 50M triples? While some triples can appear in both datasets.

What I can think of, is to order the triples dataset by the predicate, and randomly shuffle and pick out of each predicate triples.

Comment: given that RDF triples can be represented as lines, can't you just randomly shuffle the lines and then split?

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears that your dataset is available in a format with one triple per line, you can just iterate through the file and take every row with a 50% probability to create a random subset containing approximately half of the triples.

For example, here is how to do it with AWK:

```
awk 'BEGIN { srand() } int(rand()*2)' < watdiv.100M.nt > watdiv.100M.sample.1.nt
```

Explained: In the BEGIN block, initialize the random number generator by calling the `srand()` [function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Numeric-Functions.html). When called without an argument, it will use the current date and time as the seed. If you want reproducible results, set the seed here to some fixed value. Then for each line, generate a random integer, either 0 or 1. If it is non-zero (true), print the current line.

If you want two such random subsets where each triple may appear in both, just run the command twice.

If you want two disjoint random subsets, where each triple is in exactly one of them you can do it like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN { srand() } { print > "watdiv.100M.sample." int(rand()*2) ".nt" }' < watdiv.100M.nt
```